# Building html table using php

Tags: php, html

I am looking to have a table built using php but with a twist. I want to only limit it to 10 rows. If the variable is greater than 10, then a new column is added. IE:

If the variable is 9 then the table will have 1 column and 9 rows. If the number is 19 then the table will contain 10 rows and 2 columns with the second columns containing numbers 11 - 19. And so on Similar to below

```
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
| Q  | Tally | Total | Q  | Tally | Total | Q  | Tally | Total |
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
| 1  |       |       | 11 |       |       | 21 |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
| 2  |       |       | 12 |       |       | 22 |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
| 3  |       |       | 13 |       |       | 23 |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
| 4  |       |       | 14 |       |       | 24 |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
| 5  |       |       | 15 |       |       | 25 |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
| 6  |       |       | 16 |       |       |    |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
| 7  |       |       | 17 |       |       |    |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
| 8  |       |       | 18 |       |       |    |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
| 9  |       |       | 19 |       |       |    |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
| 10 |       |       | 20 |       |       |    |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+----+-------+-------+
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

I have gotten this far

```
$table_string = 'Table Name 1:45,Table Name 2:20,Table Name 3:9';

function foo()
{
    $tables = explode(',', $table_string);
    $output = '';

    foreach ($tables as $table)
    {
        $table_name = explode(':', $table)[0];
        $table_rows = explode(':',$table)[1];
        $table_columns = ceil($table_rows/10);

        $output .= "<br>

        <table class='table table-bordered table-small'>
            <tr>
                <th scope='col' colspan='99'>{$table_name}</th>
            </tr>";

        for ($x = 1; $x <=10; $x++)
        {
            $output .= "<tr>";

            for ($y = 1; $y <= $table_columns * 3; $y++)
            {
                if ($y % 3 == 1) {
                    $output .= "<td scope=\"col\">Q</td>";
                } else if ($y % 3 == 2) {
                    $output .= "<td scope=\"col\">Tally</td>";
                } else  {
                    $output .= "<td scope=\"col\">Total</td>";
                }
            }

            $output .= "</tr>";
            $output .= "<tr>";

            for ($y = 1; $y <= $table_columns * 3; $y++)
            {
                if ($y == 1 || $y % 4 == 0) {
                    $z = ceil($y / 4);
                    $output .= "<td scope=\"row\">{$z}</td>";
                } else {
                    $output .= "<td></td>";
                }
            }

            $output .= "</tr>";
        }

        $output .= "</table>";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

To help answer the question more: Here is the current output I get:

```
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
| Q | Tally | Total | Q | Tally | Total | Q | Tally | Total | Q | Tally | Total | Q | Tally | Total |
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
| 1 |       |       | 1 |       |       |   | 2     |       |   |       | 3     |   |       |       |
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
| 1 |       |       | 1 |       |       |   | 2     |       |   |       | 3     |   |       |       |
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
| 1 |       |       | 1 |       |       |   | 2     |       |   |       | 3     |   |       |       |
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
| 1 |       |       | 1 |       |       |   | 2     |       |   |       | 3     |   |       |       |
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
| 1 |       |       | 1 |       |       |   | 2     |       |   |       | 3     |   |       |       |
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
| 1 |       |       | 1 |       |       |   | 2     |       |   |       | 3     |   |       |       |
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
| 1 |       |       | 1 |       |       |   | 2     |       |   |       | 3     |   |       |       |
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
| 1 |       |       | 1 |       |       |   | 2     |       |   |       | 3     |   |       |       |
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
| 1 |       |       | 1 |       |       |   | 2     |       |   |       | 3     |   |       |       |
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
| 1 |       |       | 1 |       |       |   | 2     |       |   |       | 3     |   |       |       |
+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-------+-------+
```

Comment: what issues/errors are you facing?

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: By the way, you should declare your function this way `function foo($table_string) { /* your code */ }` to avoir `Undefined variable: table_string`

Comment: @Cid THis is just an example of the simplified code, the actual function fecthes the var the way you mention

Comment: Why not build a dummy table with all your values and make it responsive ?

Comment: @Cid Because the table is being used in a PDF conversion, so needs to be already in the shape above

Comment: @JohanRheeder What is a problem of your code? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @MaximFedorov I want to be able to build a table that can hold 3 columns per 10 rows and split the variable into sets of 10 as the statement above.

Ie if I have a var of 9, then I only need 3 columns and the first 9 rows will have a value (1-9). If however, I have a var of 25 then I need 9 columns (3 sets of 3), the first is 1-10, the second set is 11-20 and the third set is 21-25 (see example above)

Comment: @JohanRheeder Just to highlight you that you might want to try some of the functions I used to simplify your code, they're quite handy. I'm telling you because I feel my answer hasn't been noticed at all. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You should calculate count of columns: 
if a count of records is multiple of ten then count of columns is equal **count of records / 10** otherwise count of columns is equal **count of records / 10 + 1**. Code example:

```
$rowCount = 10;
$colCount = intval($recordCount / $rowCount);
if ($recordCount % $rowCount !== 0 ) {
    $colCount++;
}
```

2.You should calculate index of a row in the table for each element and build array of table rows. This index can be calculated with help the following formula: **index of an element % count of rows**. Count example:

```
$rows = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $recordCount; $i++) {
    $index = $i % $rowCount;
    $rows[$index][] = [
        'Q' => $i+1,
        'Tally' => '', // you can set value 
        'Total' => '', // you can set value
    ];
}
```

As can you see this algorithm is very simple and its asymptotic complexity is O(n)

3.You should render header with help count of columns. Code example:

```
$output .= '<tr>';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $colCount; $i++) {
    $output .= '<td scope="col">Q</td>
        <td scope="col">Tally</td>
        <td scope="col">Total</td>';
}
$output .= '</tr>';
```

4.You should render other parts of a table with help array of table rows. Code example:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $output .= '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $element) {
        $output .= "<td>{$element['Q']}</td><td></td><td></td>";
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';

}
```

Full code:

```
function buildTable($name, $rowCount, $recordCount)
{
    //calculating of count rows
    $colCount = intval($recordCount / $rowCount);
    if ($recordCount % $rowCount !== 0 ) {
        $colCount++;
    }

    // making of row array
    $rows = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $recordCount; $i++) {
        $index = $i % $rowCount;
        $rows[$index][] = [
            'Q' => $i+1,
            'Tally' => '', // you can set value
            'Total' => '', // you can set value
        ];
    }

    // render header
    $output = "<table class='table table-bordered table-small'>
        <tr>
            <th scope='col' colspan='99'>{$name}</th>
        </tr>";

    $output .= '<tr>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $colCount; $i++) {
        $output .= '<td scope="col">Q</td>
            <td scope="col">Tally</td>
            <td scope="col">Total</td>';
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';

    // render other parts of table
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $output .= '<tr>';
        foreach ($row as $element) {
            $output .= "<td>{$element['Q']}</td><td></td><td></td>";
        }
        $output .= '</tr>';

    }

    $output .= "</table>";

    return $output;

}


$tablename = 'test';
$recordCount = 25;
$rowCount = 10;
echo buildTable($tablename, $rowCount, $recordCount);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what was needed

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
    //no. of ques
    $total_ques = 45;
    //creating array for que no
    $que_nos = range(1,(int)$total_ques);
    $part = 10;

    //splitting array in chunks
    $cols = array_chunk($que_nos,$part);

    echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="5">';
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($cols as $col) {
        //Generating heading columns
        echo "<td>Q</td>";
        echo "<td>Tally</td>";
        echo "<td>Total</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    //data for each row
    $row_data = [];
    for ($i=0; $i < $part; $i++) {
        //temporary variable containing values for each row
        $temp_row_data = [];
        foreach($cols as $k1 => $col) {
            //getting first value of array
            $value = reset($col);
            $temp_row_data[] = $value ?: '';
            if ($value !== false) {
                //unset value as it is already processed
                unset($cols[$k1][array_search($value,$col)]);
            }
        }
        //storing temporary array in main row array
        $row_data[] = $temp_row_data;
    }

    foreach ($row_data as $key => $cd) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($cd as $c) {
            echo "<td>{$c}</td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/bmXmt)

The output will be like as below in the image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
<?php

// -------- Functions --------
function foo($tables_string)
{
    // Decompose tables string
    $tables = explode(',', $tables_string);

    // Header of the 3 columns
    $headers = "<td class='bg_gray' scope='col'>Q</td>"
             . "<td class='bg_gray' scope='col'>Tally</td>"
             . "<td class='bg_gray' scope='col'>Total</td>";

    // Starts output empty
    $output = "";

    // For each table string
    foreach ($tables as $table)
    {
        // Use of list() to store explode in multiple variables
        list($table_name, $table_rows) = explode(':', $table);

        // Calculate number of columns
        $table_columns = ceil($table_rows/10);

        // Starts table
        $output .= "<br>
        <table class='table table-bordered table-small'>
          <tr>
            <th scope='col' colspan='99'>{$table_name}</th>
          </tr>";

        // Use str_repeat() instead of a loop
        $output .= "<tr>".str_repeat($headers, $table_columns)."</tr>";  

        // Loop for trs
        for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++)
        {
            $output .= "<tr>";
            // Loop for tds
            for ($y = 0; $y < $table_columns * 3; $y++)
            {
                //z = number of the “row”
                $z = (10 * $y / 3) + $x;

                // If first column, and not end of our data
                if(($y % 3 == 0) && ($z <= $table_rows)){
                    $output .= "<td scope='row'>{$z}</td>";
                } else {
                    $output .= "<td> </td>";
                }
            }

            // End of table row
            $output .= "</tr>";
        }

        // End of table
        $output .= "</table>";
    }

    return $output;
}


// -------- Main script --------

// Stylize the output
echo "<style>
        table { border-collapse: collapse; }
        td { padding: 4px 8px; border: 1px solid gray; }
        .bg_gray { background: lightgray; }
    </style>";

// Use the function above
$tables = 'Table Name 1:45,Table Name 2:20,Table Name 3:9';
echo foo($tables);

?>
```

… in which I did the following:

- Tried to not change much your coding philosophy (because you must want to populate the other columns),
- Tried to comment a lot of things for better understanding,
- Correct some things, enhance some others (see comments for details),
- Added some styling for better visibility of the output.
- Tested here, where you can see the output as HTML: http://www.writephponline.com/

Some of the functions I used to simplify:

[list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)
[str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-repeat.php)

⋅
⋅
⋅

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I over complicated things, but I tried to approach this a little bit different :)

```
interface DrawableTable
{
    public function draw ();
}

class Table implements DrawableTable
{

    const MAX_ALLOWED_ROWS = 10;

    protected $name;
    protected $rows;
    protected $cols;

    /**
     * @var TableHeaderContract $header
     */
    protected $header;

    /**
     * @var TableBodyContract $body
     */
    protected $body;

    public function __construct ($name, $rows, $cols)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->rows = $rows;
        $this->cols = $cols;

        $this->header = new TableHeader(ceil($this->cols / self::MAX_ALLOWED_ROWS), ['Q', 'Tally', 'Total']);
        $this->body = new TableBody(self::MAX_ALLOWED_ROWS);

        //Here I am adding random numbers but you can call body and add as you need them!
        for ($randI = 1; $randI <= $this->cols; $randI++) {
            $this->body->addRow(new Row($randI, '', ''));
        }
    }

    public function draw ()
    {
        return (new TableMarshaller)($this);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName ()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getRows ()
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCols ()
    {
        return $this->cols;
    }

    /**
     * @return TableHeaderContract
     */
    public function getHeader ()
    {
        return $this->header;
    }

    /**
     * @return TableBodyContract
     */
    public function getBody ()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

}

interface TableHeaderContract
{
    public function drawHeaders ();
}

class TableHeader implements TableHeaderContract
{

    protected $repetitions;

    protected $headers = [];

    public function __construct ($repetitions, $headers = [])
    {
        $this->repetitions = $repetitions;
        $this->addHeadersAccordingToRows($headers);
    }

    private function addHeadersAccordingToRows ($headers)
    {
        for ($iteration = 0; $iteration < $this->repetitions; $iteration++) {
            $this->headers = array_merge($this->headers, $headers);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getHeaders ()
    {
        return $this->headers;
    }

    public function drawHeaders ()
    {
        return (new HeaderThreeMarshaller)($this);
    }
}

class Row
{
    protected $id;
    protected $tally;
    protected $total;

    public function __construct ($id, $tally, $total)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->tally = $tally;
        $this->total = $total;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId ()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     *
     * @return Row
     */
    public function setId ($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTally ()
    {
        return $this->tally;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $tally
     *
     * @return Row
     */
    public function setTally ($tally)
    {
        $this->tally = $tally;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTotal ()
    {
        return $this->total;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $total
     *
     * @return Row
     */
    public function setTotal ($total)
    {
        $this->total = $total;
        return $this;
    }
}

interface TableBodyContract
{
    public function drawBody ();
}

class TableBody implements TableBodyContract
{

    protected $allowedRowSize;

    /**
     * @var array $rows Multi Dimentional array!
     */
    protected $rows = [];

    public function __construct ($maxRowSize)
    {
        $this->allowedRowSize = $maxRowSize;
    }

    public function addRow (Row $row)
    {
        //$this->rows[(int)(floor($row->getId() % 10))][] = $row;

        //Makes sure to instanciate all allowed rows
        if (count($this->rows) < $this->allowedRowSize) {
            $this->rows[count($this->rows)][] = $row;
            return $this;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->rows); $i++) {
            if (array_key_exists($i + 1, $this->rows)) {
                // if current have euqal or less values than the next, means we need to add it here!
                if (count($this->rows[$i]) < count($this->rows[($i + 1)])) {
                    $this->rows[$i][] = $row;
                    return $this;
                } else if (count($this->rows[$i]) <= count($this->rows[count($this->rows) - 1])) {
                    $this->rows[$i][] = $row;
                    return $this;
                }
                continue;
            }
        }

        $this->rows[count($this->rows) - 1][] = $row;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRows ()
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }

    public function drawBody ()
    {
        return (new BodyMarshaller)($this);
    }

}


/**
 * MARSHALLERS TO PARSE TO YOUR VIEW
 */
class TableMarshaller
{

    /**
     * @var Table $table
     */
    protected $table;

    protected $htmlOutput;

    public function __invoke (Table $table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;

        //Wrap table into a div
        $this->htmlOutput = '<div>';
        //Table -> Name
        $this->attachTableName();

        //Table -> Header and Body
        $this->attachTableContent();

        $this->htmlOutput .= '</div>';

        return $this->htmlOutput;
    }

    private function attachTableName ()
    {
        $this->htmlOutput .= sprintf('<h2>%s</h2>', $this->table->getName());
    }

    private function attachTableContent ()
    {
        $this->htmlOutput .= '<table class="table table-bordered table-small">';
        $this->htmlOutput .= $this->table->getHeader()->drawHeaders();
        $this->htmlOutput .= $this->table->getBody()->drawBody();
        $this->htmlOutput .= '</table>';
    }

}

class HeaderThreeMarshaller
{

    public function __invoke (TableHeaderContract $tableHeader)
    {
        $htmlOutput = '<theader>';

        foreach ($tableHeader->getHeaders() as $headTitle) {
            if (!empty($headTitle)) {
                $htmlOutput .= sprintf('<th>%s</th>', $headTitle);
            }
        }

        $htmlOutput .= '</theader>';

        return $htmlOutput;
    }

}

class BodyMarshaller
{

    public function __invoke (TableBodyContract $body)
    {
        $htmlOutput = '<body>';

        foreach ($body->getRows() as $rowNum => $rows) {
            $htmlOutput .= '<tr>';

            /**
             * @var Row $row
             */
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $htmlOutput .= sprintf(
                    '<td>%d</td><td>%s</td><td>%d</td>',
                    $row->getId(),
                    $row->getTally(),
                    $row->getTotal()
                );
            }

            $htmlOutput .= '</tr>';
        }

        $htmlOutput .= '</body>';

        return $htmlOutput;
    }
}
```

And here is how you can test its generation. So for the example below:

```
$table = new Table('Test Example 1', 5, 85);

print $table->draw();
```

You can copy the [code example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b91029a8920a29146e0daa781bf90ddb050517f) I created and check its output on a HTML file!